# thymeleaf javascript onload=location.href

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

Hopefully this is a simple syntax question:

I want to create an onload statement that, when compiled, will look as follows:

```
<body onload="location.href='#tutanchor'">
```

My expression language attempt is as follows:

```
<body th:attr="onload='location.href='+${anchorname}">
```

This doesn't work because it is missing the single quotes round the anchor.
But if I add additional single quotes, thymeleaf cannot parse.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `&apos;`?

```
<body th:attr="onload='location.href=&apos;'+${anchorname}+'&apos;'">
```

I'm not familiar with thymeleaf, so this may not work as I expect.  [The documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#text-literals) suggests that `\` is the escape character for quotes.  If `&apos;` doesn't work, try escaping the quotes:

```
<body th:attr="onload='location.href=\''+${anchorname}+'\''">
```

It begs the question, why not just [use a `<script>` tag](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart)?

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    location.href = /*[[${anchorname}]]*/ '#';
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: Error on first suggestion is: Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as assignation sequence: "onload='location.href=''+${anchorname}+'''" (xzcreatetesttype:9)
 at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.AssignationUtils.parseAssignationSequence(AssignationUtils.java:67). HANG ON, I'll try the second now

Comment: second suggestion (escape characters) doesn't crash, but I get the following link (which obviously doesn't work):  <body onload="location.href=&#39;#tutAnchor&#39;">

Comment: It doesn't work?  It should.  `&#39;` is the same as `&apos;`.  Both are ways of expressing `'` as HTML.

Comment: I know, but alas it doesn't seem to respond. Checked my template. <a id="tutanchor"></a> is right where it should be and the hardcoded <body onload="location.href='#tutanchor'"> works. Thinking of moving to a window.onload and taking it from there, but then I have to figure out how to only call javascript if ${anchorname} is not null

Comment: Case sensitive. Note the case of the A in tutAnchor/tutanchor.

Comment: oops! :) It is now working using the second suggestion you provided. Thanks a million!